# Complex math involving detecting Sine patterns

Tags: php, design-patterns, math, trigonometry

Hoping to find a math+PHP genius to solve this. One of my clients (a surgeon) wants a web-app tied to his patients' EEG machines that track heartbeats. 
The data is a live feed in table format (already done)...but what I need is to constantly compare the patient's heartbeat to a resting heart-rate baseline. If the patient's heartbeat gets over or under a certain threshold, an alarm and notification is sent via push to the doctor's iPhone/Android.

This is part of an overall software we're building and testing...it would be an amazing feature. The challenging part is the math needed to compare all the live data and basically notify when the data curve is or is not a SINE wave of certain amplitude and frequency. The sample data can be buffered for 20minutes or more for long-term, constant analysis.

PHP is the language, data stored in MySQL DBs. Would love to hire someone to outsource this problem so if you have a solution or need more details, respond!!

Comment: doesnt the machine has it's own monitoring and alert system? if yes, couldn't you just push the alerts and rely on the machine to track patient state changes ?

Comment: I agree. Not to be an asshole, but unless you are already familiar with writing medical systems, or at least have a very detailed list of requirements and testing procedures, you should really stay away from this type of equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to compare a complex signal like a heartbeat to a sine wave sounds like it's doomed to failure.  A glance at a typical EKG trace and some knowledge of FFT tells you that.

A complex transient will be the superposition of lots of sine and cosine terms, each with different amplitudes and frequencies.  It's possible to pick out individual terms, but I'm not sure how meaningful it'll be.

Floating point number comparisons are another issue.  What if the reference wave has amplitude and frequency 10.0 and 60.0.  Is a wave with amplitude and frequency 10.25 and 62.1 "the same"?  What's your criterion for sending out the alarm and notification?  What's the likelihood of false positives?  Your design won't be popular if it has the staff running to check false alarms constantly.